# Why does Rudeus keep using Zariff’s Arm?

Tags: mushoku-tensei

Since Rudeus's arm got regenerated

> after he accepted becoming Dragon God Orstred's collaborator(?),

he's seen using the Zariff’s Arm when he fights one of the North Style Emperors. Why? Is there a specific reason that he keeps using it?